# How to disable the whole week in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my project i have a requirement that if there is a public holiday in the week disable the whole week suppose if july 4 th is holiday and if it is wednesday i have to disable that particular whole week. I am able todisable the particular days with beforeshowday function but I am not sure how can i disable the whole week.Can anyone please help me with this

```
 var disabledDays = ["1-1", "7-4", "12-25", "11-11"];
$("#survey_f_day").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disableAllTheseDays,
    maxDate: '-4'
});
function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
if (($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d, disabledDays) != -1))
    return [false];
else return [true];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the exapmles provided in this link, I think may its helpful for you.

http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/how-to-disable-dates-in-jquery-datepicker-a-short-guide/

or try

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({
     format: "yy-mm-dd",
     datesDisabled: ["2018-09-10"]
});
```